# how to get value of array item under another array in node js?

Tags: arrays, node.js

```
MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db(db_name);
    dbo.collection("assets").aggregate([
        { $lookup:
           {
               from: 'employee',
               localField: 'assign_to',
               foreignField: 'employee_id',
               as: 'employee_details'
           }
        }
    ]).sort({_id:-1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.status(200).json({'return_data': result });
        db.close();
    });
});
```

i want to get employee name from employee details

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: how to get sku value from this array in node js
{
"_id" : 1,
"item" : "almonds",
"price" : 12,
"quantity" : 2,
"inventory_docs" : [
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "almonds", "description" : "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
]
}
{
"_id" : 2,
"item" : "pecans",
"price" : 20,
"quantity" : 1,
"inventory_docs" : [
{ "_id" : 4, "sku" : "pecans", "description" : "product 4", "instock" : 70 }
]
}
{
"_id" : 3,
"inventory_docs" : [
{ "_id" : 5, "sku" : null, "description" : "Incomplete" },
{ "_id" : 6 }
]
}

Comment: Remember to upvote and mark the answer as correct if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic ways you can do this is using a nested loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < re.length; ++i){

  //Resolves to true if you are in the inner array
  if(re[i].inventory_docs){
    inventory=re[i].inventory_docs;

    //Get the value out using object notation
    for( let j = 0; j < inventory.length; ++j)
      console.log(inventory[j].sku);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please wrote this in angular 6 html page

Comment: Angular was never mentioned in your original post, which is why I had asked you to provide enough details of what you're trying to achieve.